# How to get the id of all the materials?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

help me

```
public function indexAction() 
{


$tpos = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TestBundle:Materials')->findAll();

foreach($tposs as $tpos) {
     $posts['id'];
} 

echo $midcount;
```

how will you?

Notice: Undefined index: id

Answer (score 1):

```
$materials = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TestBundle:Materials')->findAll();
$materialIds = array();
foreach ($materials as $material) {
    $materialIds[] = $material->getId();
}
```